# Parse XML string that starts with "=" sign

Tags: php, xml

I am currently writing an endpoint in `PHP` that is supposed to read `XML` from POST request. So far I have the following:

```
$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

So the incoming XML string is something like `xmlmsg= <message date="27/09/2018 14:05:40">xml content...</message>`

I need to parse this string and update some data in my database. I have tried to parse with `SimpleXMLElement`, but I was unable to get any results. I just can't find a way to parse an XML that starts with `xmlmsg=`.

What is it and how can I read the XML content?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is not valid XML which is why the XML parser fails. That looks like something like a "macro definition" internally using some XML string. Use a regular expression to parse it.

Comment: Usually you'd get that using `$_POST['xmlmsg']` if it's a urlencoded form request